# Pass -D parameter to maven from m2eclipse run dialog

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm wondering how to pass parameters to maven's command line from the m2eclipse dialog.

This is the script (bat) that I want to create a configuration for - using m2eclipse:

```
@echo off
set HOST_NAME=localhost.fds.com
set SECURE_ASSETS_PORT=9678

title Running Legacy Application

mvn -Dhostname=%HOST_NAME% -DASSET_SERVER_URL_OVERRIDE=https://%HOST_NAME%:%SECURE_ASSETS_PORT% -Dassets.port.num=9876 -Dassets.secure.port.num=%SECURE_ASSETS_PORT jetty:run -P assets
```

[image: This is the run as maven build dialog]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's what the parameter name and value part is for.  I think you leave the -D off though.